# HP ProLiant DL120 G7 boot stuck due to disabled raid controller

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, dedicated-server, bios

After I have enabled RAID I disabled the B110i raid controller in the BIOS. Now it is stuck on a POST message and I can't do anything. Pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> to re-enter the BIOS settings does nothing. It remains stuck there... The server is remotely managed through ILO3. How can i do a BIOS reset or any solution without manual intervention?